# PayPal Payments Advanced + PayFlow Link

Tags: paypal

I keep getting the following error when trying to submit a sandbox payment through my PayFlow Gateway:

> Error: There was a problem processing your request. Please press the
>   Back button of your browser and then refresh the page. If you continue
>   to have an issue, please contact us.

I'm using the following code to generate my PayFlow Gateway, but I just can't get it to work.

```
/* PayPal Payments Advanced */

$PF_USER        = 'my_user';
$PF_VENDOR  = 'my_vendor';
$PF_PARTNER     = 'PayPal';
$PF_PWD     = 'my_pass';
$PF_MODE        = 'TEST';
$PF_HOST_ADDR   = 'https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com'; // TEST mode
// $PF_HOST_ADDR = 'https://payflowpro.paypal.com' // LIVE mode

$secureTokenId  = uniqid('',true);
$postData       = "USER=".$PF_USER
                ."&VENDOR=".$PF_VENDOR
                ."&PARTNER=".$PF_PARTNER
                ."&PWD=".$PF_PWD

                ."&SECURETOKENID=".$secureTokenId
                ."&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y"
                ."&TRXTYPE=S"
                ."&AMT=1.00"

                ."&BILLTOFIRSTNAME=".$first_name
                ."&BILLTOLASTNAME=".$last_name
                ."&BILLTOSTREET=".$address
                ."&BILLTOCITY=".$city
                ."&BILLTOSTATE=".$state
                ."&BILLTOZIP=".$zip
                ."&BILLTOCOUNTRY=".$country

                ."&SHIPTOFIRSTNAME=".$first_name
                ."&SHIPTOLASTNAME=".$last_name
                ."&SHIPTOSTREET=".$address
                ."&SHIPTOCITY=".$city
                ."&SHIPTOSTATE=".$state
                ."&SHIPTOZIP=".$zip
                ."&SHIPTTOCOUNTRY=".$country

                ."&EMAIL=".$email
                ."&PHONENUM=".$phone;

/* Initialize and Setup Request */

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$PF_HOST_ADDR);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);

/* Ready the postData to send */

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postData);

/* Send the data to PayPal and assign response */

$resp = curl_exec($ch);

/* Confirm response and handle */

if(!$resp){
    $error = '<p>There was an error processing your order.</p>';    
}

/* Parse and assign to array */

parse_str($resp,$arr);

if($arr['RESULT'] != 0) {
    // handle error
    die($arr['RESULT']);
    $error = '<p>There was an error processing your order. '.$arr['RESULT'].'</p>';
}

echo '<iframe src="https://payflowlink.paypal.com?mode='.$PF_MODE.'&amp;SECURETOKEN='.$arr['SECURETOKEN'].'&amp;SECURETOKENID='.$secureTokenId.'" width="550" height="565" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" border="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>';
```

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Where are you receiving this error? If you're getting that error on a paypal page (within the iframe) then we're going to need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to explicitly set my Firefox privacy settings to "Allow" third-party cookies. Doing this made the error message go away. I didn't have this problem on Safari.